# Update Custom Attributes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, syntax-error

I am trying to write a script that will import a csv file and update a set of custom attributes that were built into our AD Schema.

Here is the basic code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$USERS = Import-Csv c:\temp\test2.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADComputer -filter {dnsname -eq $user.ComputerName} |
    Set-ADComputer -replace @{bSBPrimaryUser = $user.bSBPrimaryUser}
}
```

Here is my Error Message:

> Set-ADComputer : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   At C:\Users\nwatson\Documents\Update Computers.ps1:7 char:24
>
> - Set-ADComputer -replace <<<<  @{bSBPrimaryUser = $user.bSBPrimaryUser}}
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADComputer

For some reason if I write a basic command like below it works, but not in the array.

```
Set-ADComputer as-001  -replace @{ bSBPrimaryUser = "Joe Smith";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the property you are looking for isn't `dnsname` but `dnshostname` or `name`. (If just using name, then skip using filter and pass it in as the `identity`)

Second, the filters on the AD cmdlets aren't straight forward. If using curly braces, then you can't use an expression. Double quotes then single quotes seems to work fine though.

```
Get-ADComputer -filter "dnshostname -eq '$($user.ComputerName)'"
```

Alternatively, define the expression as a variable.

```
$ComputerName = $user.ComputerName
Get-ADComputer -filter {dnshostname -eq $Computername}
```

Comment: So I made your changes along with setting the primary user as a variable also. Along with some testing and outputting my veriables to make sure I got what I wanted to see, it worked.   Thank you so much, saves me hours of manual editing!

Comment: So I also did a little testing, if the computer name is wrong it skips over it. That's a good thing. But how can I create a log to document what computer names it did not skip?

Comment: Rather than piping from get to set. Save the output of get in a variable. Then you can do something like `if ($null -ne $get) {set} else {write-host error on $computername}`

Comment: Also if solution worked for you, you should accept it.